# Android achartengine text label margin and padding

Tags: android, margin, padding, achartengine

[image]

Hi developers, I have a question: how can I make the gap between labels and bars smaller, I've tried setting the margin of XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to a different range(both positive and negative), but that doesn't affect the gap between labels and bars. And also passing negative value into renderer.setXLabelPadding() seems to be ignored - the text labels are on the X axis since the graph is rotated 90%

I am using achartengine 1.1.0, which should be the latest.

Here's a section of the code that I used to manipulate the apperance:

```
    renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL); //horizontal bar-graph
    renderer.clearXTextLabels();
    renderer.setYLabels(0); //remove units on the Y axis(the horizontal axis since the graph has been rotated 90 degree)
    renderer.setXLabels(0); //removes 'values' from the X-Axis
    renderer.setMargins(new int[]{10, 0, 90, 0}); //top, left, bottom, right. Since its a horizontal bar graph, the margins has been rotated clock-wise. setting them to negative doesn't solve my problem.

    renderer.addXTextLabel(0.9, "Average");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(1.2, "Maximum");
    renderer.setXLabelsPadding(-200f); //no effect
    renderer.setYLabelsPadding(-200f); //no effect
```

Comment: No, my final solution was to create my own bar chart library.

Answer (score 0):

try render.setBarSpacing(float); for spacing between bars. I used this and it worked.